# Why is there a "==" inside String.equals?

Tags: java, string

Why Java is comparing (this == another String) inside equalsIgnoreCase method for checking a string insensitive?

Also, String equals is comparing (this == another String) to compare two objects?

Java 6: String Class equalsIgnoreCase implementation given below.

```
 public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString) {
        return (this == anotherString) ? true :
               (anotherString != null) && (anotherString.count == count) &&
           regionMatches(true, 0, anotherString, 0, count);
    }
```

Java 6: String Class equals implementation given below.

```
 public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I'd imagine because a direct object comparison is very quick, so it's a quick optimization to check if the String is being compared to itself.

Comment: Please note that actual implementation of `String.equals` is intrinsified and provided Java implementation is just the reference code (for interpretator, code analysis tools, etc.)

Comment: @TagirValeev: Iteresting! Do you have any source for this? Now days (5 years after your comment) many methods in the standard library are marked with `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate`, but `equals` is not. Are you sure it is intrinsified?

Comment: @Lii The `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` marking is just a hint for developers who would like to make a given method an intrinsic (or it's already made). This doesn't actually mean that the method is actually an intrinsic or not. You can see an actual implementation in HotSpot source code, [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/a804c6a6ef9016ab07a8172f45c6a79e72d4c841/src/hotspot/share/opto/library_call.cpp#L914).

Comment: @TagirValeev: Very interesting, thanks! I know that `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` is just a hint, but I guessed that they would put it on all methods that are intrinsic in HotSpot. Apparently I was wrong. Do you have any idea why `String#equals` haven't got one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why Java is comparing (this == another String) inside equalsIgnoreCase method for checking a string insensitive?

It's an optimization. If the reference passed in is exactly the same as `this`, then `equals` *must* return `true`, but we don't need to look at any fields etc. Everything is the same as itself. From the documentation for `Object.equals(Object)`:

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
> - ...

It's very common for an equality check to start with:

- Is the other reference equal to `this`? If so, return true.
- Is the other reference null? If so, return false.
- Does the other reference refer to an object of the wrong type? If so, return false.

*Then* you go on to type-specific checks.

Answer (score 2):

`==` is true when comparing with the same object - given an efficiency increase more likely than just about any other class due to [String *interning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Note that this code:

```
return (this == anotherString) ? true : <rest of line>
```

could have been written (more elegantly IMHO) as:

```
return this == anotherString || <rest of line>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 this == another object
```

This is the basic check in `equals` method for almost **all Objects** not just in String class. It is **efficient** and also a good practice to check this first in your own Class.
The logic is simple **if both have the same reference then they are referring to the same object always**, so they are **equal**.

You don't need any other comparison to  tell they are equal for sure if  `this == another object` is true.